# Express + Socket.io: find key in query string for every event except one

Tags: node.js, sockets, express, socket.io

I'd like permit any socket connection to my server but in the case the client connects without specifying a 'username' in *socket.handshake.query*, I want to just let him create a new account and then the server should automatically disconnect him.

The only way I could achieve it was validating *socket.handshake.query* on every event except the *signUp* event -this means runing validateQuery() on almost every event!-. I feel that this may be a very rough way. I have also tryed to implement this with middleware but I was not able to achieve the desired behaviour (I'm pretty new to Node).

This is my code, please tell me if you know a better way to implement this :)

- NOTE: A session handler is not mandatory for this case.

  'use strict';

  ```
  /*** BASE SETUP: Main objects & Dependencies            */

  var express     = require('express');
  var app         = express();
  var http        = require('http');
  var server      = http.createServer(app);
  var io          = require('socket.io');

  // Set port in which the server will listen
  var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

  // Start servers (HTTP is temporal and just for personal tests...)
  var io = io.listen(server);
  server.listen(port, function() {
    console.log('>> Express server listening on port ' + port + ' <<');
  });

  /*
   * A dummy socket validation function.
   */
  var validateQuery = function(socket, next) {    

      console.log("> Verifying username...");

      if ( typeof socket.handshake.query.username  === 'undefined' || socket.handshake.query.username === "" ) {
          console.log("-> Authentification failed!");
          socket.disconnect();
          return next(new Error("{ code: 403, description: 'You must specify a username in your query' }"));
      }
  };

  /*** SOCKET IO Events                                   */

  io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {

      console.log("> New connection stablished: "+ socket.id);


      // @ Disconnect
      //  
      socket.on('disconnect', function() {
          // clients.splice(clients.indexOf(socket.id), 1);
          console.log("> Triggered 'Disconnect' @ " + socket.id);
      }); 


      // @ SignUp             - Creates new users
      //
      socket.on('signUp', function( requestData ) {
          console.log("> Triggered 'signUp' @ " + socket.id);
          socket.emit('onSignUp', { username : requestData.username, dsp : requestData.dsp });
          socket.disconnect();
      });


      // @ getUserList        - Gets a list of all registered users
      //  
      socket.on('getUserList', function( requestData ) {

          // Validate query
          validateQuery(socket);

          // Send the user's list
          socket.emit( 'onGetUserList', userList );

      });


      // @ getUserProfile     - Gets a user's profile. Will return the requester's profile if none specified
      //  
      socket.on('getUserProfile', function( requestData ) {

          // Validate username
          validateQuery(socket);

          var userProfile = { username : "User1", dsp : "Ron" };
          socket.emit('onGetUserProfile', userProfile);
      });

  });
  ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to allow the connection without the auth, but then only allow some events to be processed if they are not authenticated, then you will have to check validation on every event that requires auth.  There's no other way around it if you're going to allow some events through without auth.

You could make the auth check a little simpler though.  When the socket first connects, you couuld do the validation and then set a custom flag on the socket object.  From then on, you can just check that flag if an event requires auth (which should be a little more efficient).

If any follow on events might change the auth status, you can then update the flag.

You could also make some shortcuts for your event handlers that require auth.

```
function addAuthEventListener(sock, event, fn) {
    sock.on(event, function (data) {
        if ( typeof sock.handshake.query.username  === 'undefined' || sock.handshake.query.username === "" ) {
            sock.disconnect();
        } else {
            return fn.apply(this, arguments)
        }        
    });
}
```

So, then any event handler that requires auth could just be installed like this:

```
addAuthEventListener(socket, 'onGetUserList', function(requestData) {
    // Send the user's list
    socket.emit( 'onGetUserList', userList );
});
```

And the auth checks would happen automatically.

Comment: Hello jfriend00, thanks a lot, your reply is useful and much 
appreciated!

I modified my code and it works. Only thing is that in the client side it's not catching the 'error' event. The only way it's catching 'error' events is if I put a `code`io.use()`code` with a middleware function that creates the new error... weird!